# jQuery: How to bind an event for the div when it becomes visible?

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

I've got a div element: 
`<div id="tab1">
    Tab data
</div>`.

How to bind a custom event when this div becomes visible (gets `display: block;`)?

And also I'd like to bind an event when this div becomes invisible (gets `display: none;`).

I'd like to do this in jQuery.

Edit:
I'm making simple tabs with ajax content. I want the content on this tabs to be ajax-updated only when the tab is visible.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context to what you're doing?

Comment: While one of the commenters below gave a workable solution, I imagine it'd be smarter to bind onto custom events for when tabs are switched.  It's a lot smarter than monitoring page content visibility.

Comment: Please share some of your Ajax code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start and stop the AJAX update based on the visibility. You can use **[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** to return a TRUE or FALSE for **[`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)**:

```
var timer; // Variable to start and top updating timer

  // This if statement has to be part of the event handler for the visibility
  //   change of selector..... so there might be more straight forward solution
  //   see the last example in this answer.
if ($(selector).is(":visible"))
{
    // Start / continue AJAX updating
    timer = setInterval(AJAXupdate, 1000);
} else
{
    // Stop AJAX updating
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Here is a simple example of a timer that stops when it is invisible. Note that the numbers don't keep increasing when they're not visible:

```
(function() {    

    var switcher;                             // variable to start and stop timer

      // Function / event that will be started and stopped
    function count() {
        $("div").html(1 + parseInt($("div").html(), 10));
    }

    $(function() {                                               // <== doc ready

          // Start timer - it is visible by default
        switcher = setInterval(count, 1000);

        $("input").click(function() {

            $("div").toggle();                         // Toggle timer visibility

              // Start and stop timer based on visibility
            if ($("div").is(":visible"))
            {
                switcher = setInterval(count, 1000);
            } else
            {
                clearInterval(switcher);            
            }
        });
    });
}());
​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nX4bg/)**

---

Of course, in the above case, and maybe your case, it's more straight forward to simple alternately turn the update on and off:

```
(function() {    

    var switcher;

    function count() {
        $("div").html(1 + parseInt($("div").html(), 10));
    }

    $(function() {

        switcher = setInterval(count, 1000);

        $("input").toggle(function() { 
            clearInterval(switcher);
            $("div").toggle(); }, 
        function() {                        
            switcher = setInterval(count, 1000);
            $("div").toggle();
        });

    });

}());
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CSZLF/)**

Comment: My question was not about how to start/stop sending ajax requests, but about how to bind an event to div when it becomes visible (when the tab is active).

Comment: @SaltLake - Yeah. jsFiddle is pretty useful and fun!

Answer (score 3):

Have the event always bound to the div, but inside the event, do something like the following:

```
if($(self).is(":visible")){
    // Implement your code
}
```

Now your event will only be triggered if the element is visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to fire up `focus` event when the tab is selected.

```
var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.each(function(){

        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        if ( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
            $(this).focus(); // fire this event if tab is visible
        } else {
            $(this).blur(); // if tab is invisible
        }
    });
});
```

And then I catch these `focus` and `blur` events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabID").bind("focus",function(){
        if ( $(this).is(":visible") ) {
            // start ajax here
        }
    });

    $("#tab'.$key.'").bind("blur",function(){
        if ( !$(this).is(":visible") ) {
            // stop ajax here
        }
    });
});
```