# Jquery - When Div gets visible

Tags: jquery

Hey everbody, im getting some trouble here.

Is jQuery capable to tell me when a div "appers" (not gets visible, i mean, when it not gets display block, it just appears on the screen) and give me an a alert?

I have to get an alert when my div reaches the screen.

Thanks for anything!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery(event): watch element style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567987/jqueryevent-watch-element-style)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording. It sounds like you may be defining "appears" as "when it appears as a result of scrolling the page". Is that right?

Comment: Have a look  


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859034/jquery-how-to-bind-an-event-for-the-div-when-it-becomes-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the script tag for your alert within the div element. That way, the code will only be executed when the div is shown. If a browser blocks the div, the code won't run and you won't get your alert.