# With javascript how do you time when a DIV is visible and then record that time length to a local DataBase

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, database

I am trying to record how long a person remains on a page in a web app, when viewed on an iOS device, and then record that number, if over 2 seconds, to a local database. Of course the app is written in HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript so the page is actually just a DIV that slides, fades etc. in/out of view on the iDevice.

The app will be used offline and the data will be recorded locally until the user goes to the server to update the app with weekly content. At that time the content from the local database will be transferred to the server.

I have a database created (CBNapp) and the necessary table (CBNapp_Usage) with a column for each page (NewKnife, Trivia, True, Musings, Jokes, Movies, Stories). My idea is to record each time to the appropriate column. In this way I can count the entries under each column to get page visits and use the actual seconds to determine average length of a page's visit etc. I would then record the time of the download to the server and subtract it from their previous download date to get a time frame for the recorded usage.

I have researched this for a while and have come across a question here on stackoverflow at

[jQuery: How to bind an event for the div when it becomes visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859034/jquery-how-to-bind-an-event-for-the-div-when-it-becomes-visible)

that has an answer (the last one seems best to me) that I think will work but I can not seem to transfer it to my specific needs. This is my first web app. I am ok at HTML and CSS but a newcomer to JavaScript and jQuery so I will need specific examples to understand. Please be gentle :-)

The DIVs I need to record the visits on, all have a `class of "root"` and have ids as follows:

```
ContentNewKnife
ContentTrivia
ContentTrue
ContentMusings
ContentJokes
ContentMovies
ContentStories
```

I tried to identify the DIVs using the following

```
    var ContentPages = $("div#[id*=Content]") and $(div.root);
```

which throws an error.

Could anyone show me how to do what I am trying to accomplish either using the code referenced above or with a completely new approach.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Ted

Comment: If you start a timer, then that will eat up the processor of the mobile device. A better way might be to capture the date and time initially and then capture the end date and time and subtract. Food for thought.

Comment: I never thought of that. Is a timer that CPU intensive? Could your method capture seconds better/easier?

Comment: The date method goes down to the millisecond, so either would give you about the same amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the first thing you need to do is to capture the time.

I start an interval that updates every second (1000 ms). This rounds up the seconds you will notice. If you want more precise, you can have the timer go 500ms or even 100ms and then divide to get seconds).

Then you trigger the start and stop on the existing pre and post page transition events.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/akEEx/6/

Rather than build this from the ground up, you might consider using an out-of-the-box mobile analytics program:

I'd recommend http://www.localytics.com/

but these might work too:

https://mixpanel.com

http://urbanairship.com/

http://www.flurry.com/

The benefit is that you can capture a lot more than just time on page or content. And it can integrate with any online stuff you might want to do.

Comment: I will look into a per-packaged solution. I was not aware they would work offline. In the mean time, what do you need from me to proceed?

Comment: I have looked at the 4 pre-packaged solutions you suggested. All but Flurry seem to require a native iOS app. Flurry at the moment is not accepting further people for their HTML5 version.

Comment: Start by creating the initial HTML5 application. Checkout http://html5boilerplate.com/ Download their starter stuff and begin with that. Then decide if you are going to use Jquery Mobile or Sencha as the framework for your HTML5 application. Then you need to put it in a place such as Github where others can see and work on it.

Comment: Here is how to make a web app with storage: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/how-to-create-offline-webapps-on-the-iphone

Google Analytics might also be able to store offline web application data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618719/how-does-google-analytics-for-android-handle-offline-app-usage

Comment: The app is created I am just trying to put the mechanics to it now. Test app is at http://getappx10.coffeebreaknews.com. Some background might help. We publish a local weekly paper in Yellowknife Canada. It is very specific to Yellowknife with local PSAs, Movie info etc. There are different areas of interest displayed on the different content pages I outlined above. It is not going in the AppStore. The app must work offline as the Internet in the area is slow and unreliable. Content will change weekly being similar to our paper publication. It is sponsor supported, which is why we need stats.

Comment: That is good. Let me play around with it. So, we'll capture a date time stamp for a begin and end time, and then save that to local storage. Or do you want to do the conversion to total time in seconds before storing that data? ALSO, I am wondering why you are using JQ 1.3.2 and not a more recent one such as 1.6.4 or 1.7.1?

Comment: I am using mobione to develop the app and that is what they are using as a default. I have tried using later jQuery versions and they seem to work. All of the custom JavaScript is in the CBNtest_ContentMovies_custom.js file. I will upload the latest version so you can see where we are at as of today. Most of the content you see is just a place holder. The movie page is almost complete. If you have any general comments to improve the customer experience, I welcome them. What time zone are you in?

Comment: I have uploaded the newest version. All of the changes to JS are in CBNtest_ContentMovies_custom.js file. I have put comments to you specifically using @@@– User970008 comment @@@ so you can easily find them with a search.

Comment: Cool, I am looking at the now. I am in Eastern GMT-5

Comment: I would like to convert the time to seconds before it goes to the DB. Also I would like it to be stored in the DB only if it is over 2 seconds, to ensure we are not capturing simple page flips.

Comment: I don't see any comments in the html or JS. Here is my latest progress stub. I think we can do it on the click events for the buttons instead of focus on the div. Right now this just captures start time on click. http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/akEEx/1/

Comment: I have uploaded a new custom.js with comments for you highlighted as @@@– User970008 comment @@@ new comment

Comment: Do you like the date format in my example so far? e.g., 1/23/2012 15:7:40

Comment: Is it difficult to change it to seconds? I think that would be easier than having to do the math once it is in the DB.

Comment: OK, I got the first part working. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/akEEx/6/

Comment: WOW! I think that will do it! Not every page will need to be timed so if the user goes to an un-timed page the timer should stop. If there is another timer running will they effect each other? The weekly game (tap the coffee cup and tap on Mental musings) may have a timer in it. Awesome!

Comment: If you like the answer, don't forget to hit the checkmark :) It might not hurt to track all pages, though. You might use that data in the future to improve the app. So, it could be of value to you still. Glad it is working. You can have multiple timers, but I don't think you will want to. Instead, I would add some logic that would call stopCount() on some buttons or links and doTimer() on the ones that you want to record. If you find that the interval is eating up too much CPU, which for an iPhone it should be okay, you can switch to the date() method in my previous examples.

Comment: I have only been able to work on this tonight. I have created a text page located at stack.coffeebreaknews.com with code and comments.

Comment: I sent you an email but it bounced. I just resent again. This is the error: Mail server for "coffeebreaknews.com" unreachable for too long